# jump between two pages

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

i write two pages ,one page is called segment,another is crftest.First i stay at the segment page,when i press the button,i want to jump the crftest page.

the error message are here

```
at view.SegmentController.handlecrftest(SegmentController.java:33
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

here is my showcrftest function which jump the crftestpage

```
public void showcrftest(){
            // Load crftest overview.
            try{
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("../view/CRFtest.fxml"));

                crftestLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

                // Show the scene containing the layout.
                Scene scene = new Scene(crftestLayout);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();

                // Give the controller access to the main app.
                SegmentController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setMain(this);

                }catch (IOException e) {   

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
```

here is my controller the trigger function i press the button called handlecrftest()

```
public class SegmentController {
     // Reference to the main application
    private Main main;

    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }



    @FXML
    private void handlecrftest(){
        try{
            main.showcrftest();

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } 

}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the full stack trace, include the full output of the error

Comment: you want to see all of the error?

Comment: when i debug the code , i can't step into the showcrftest() function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands, your question doesn't really have enough information to answer it. In particular, you should include the full stack trace, or at least enough of it that it's possible to tell what kind of exception is being thrown, and from where in your code it is being thrown (which line is line 33?). Also, it is not clear whether `SegmentController` is the controller class for segment.fxml, or CRFtest.fxml; and more generally how the pieces of your application are wired together.